# Make SVG loaded from file overflow:visible outside <object>

Tags: css, svg, overflow

**Is there a simple way of having an SVG loaded from external file and overflowing?**

I tried this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;">
        <svg version="1.1"
             baseProfile="full"
             width="100%" height="100%"
             viewBox="0 0 300 200"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             preserveAspectRatio="none"
             overflow="visible">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
          <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="120" fill="blue" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;overflow:visible;">
        <object style='width:100%;height:100%;overflow:visible;' type='image/svg+xml' data='simple.svg'></object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

where `simple.svg` is the same as the inline `<svg>` tag. As seen in this
image:

[image]

or in this https://jsfiddle.net/bhLk69wd/1/, the SVG is clipped by `<object>`. Previously, I tried `<img>` and `<embed>` and the SVG was also clipped.

Comment: Seems fine to me, although you'd want to make the object tag have width and height 100px rather than100% so they draw the same.

Comment: I want the svg image to draw outside the rectangle of its component. Do the circle in the component at the bottom is clipped in your case?

Comment: Nope, not on Firefox.

Comment: In Linux, it is clipped in both Chrome and Firefox.